# Compare tables with BOOLEAN in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, boolean, create-table

I’m trying to compare 2 columns of different tables in my database and through this code it works, but it is printing '1' for TRUE and '0' for FALSE. What I would like it to print is TRUE and FALSE as words. I know that in the second code below, the quotes for TRUE and FALSE are missing, but if I put them I get a Warning. Can you help me solve it? I just want TRUE or FALSE to appear, not '1' and '0'.

```
SELECT s.solution_number, a.choice_answer, 
case when s.solution_number = a.choice_answer then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' 
         END  as correct_answer
FROM solution s 
INNER JOIN answers a  on s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk;


UPDATE answers a 
INNER JOIN solution s  on s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.correct_answer = case 
     when s.solution_number = a.choice_answer then TRUE else FALSE END
where s.exercise_id_fk=a.exercise_id_fk;
```

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE solution(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    solution_number INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    choice_answer INT,
    correct_answer BOOLEAN,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

Comment: boolean in MySQL is just an alias for tinyint, you cannot directly pass the values of TRUE or FALSE. A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true

Comment: ohh okay... I thought of using: `select case when your_bool_column = 1 
            then 'true'
            else 'false'
       end as bool_col
from your_table` what do you think?

Comment: your SELECT statement looks fine, I was addressing your UPDATE statement

Comment: Okey @Hunter. So maybe I should leave like this: with 1 and 0 instead of True or False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in every programming language ever in the history of mankind, TRUE and FALSE are 1 and 0. MySQL interprets them as numbers and you can't print them out as "TRUE" or "FALSE" by some config. What you can do is:

```
SELECT IF(col = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS correctAnswer
...
```

Comment: Okey, thank you for your help. Maybe I should leave it like 1 and 0 and not complicate it.

Comment: FWIW, MySQL's interpretation of true and false as the integers 1 and 0 is nonstandard. Other SQL implementations don't do this. Trying to do arithmetic on boolean values is an error in most other SQL implementations.